# How to add a new url route to an existing CakePHP (2) project

Tags: php, cakephp

A client of mine has a legacy CakePHP2 website which needs updating with a new page to produce a PDF and I'm really struggling to get the new method within the Controller to be called.

I have a lot of experience with PHP but I've not used it a great deal in the last five years and I've never touched CakePHP. The site was maintained by someone else but they asked me to take a look since that person has left.  I know the site is running a very old  version of Cake, which I've told them, but they don't want it updated at this point as it's being replaced anyway.

I've gone through the CakePHP Docs for v2 but my clients routes.php file does not seem to match up to the wildcard paths suggested in the docs.

The entry in routes.php that routes to several existing methods is:

`Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'surveys', 'action' => 'index'));`

I've then edited the Controller/SurveysController.php file to add in a new method so I could perform a simple test.

```php
    public function pdf($id, $type = 1) {
        file_put_contents("/tmp/debug.log", "inside the new method");
        // Call an existing method just to load a page
        $this->report($id);
```

I've copied the existing `Views/Survey/report.ctp` file to `Views/Survey/pdf.ctp` so, in theory, the method should be taking the same action and the view/template will also be the same.

The issue I have though is whilst I can browse to the existing URL of `surveys/report/123` if I try going to the new methods URL of `surveys/pdf/123` I am simply HTTP302  redirected to the websites index. The file I try to create within the view is not being created but as I'm not seeing a 404 page such as if I went to `/surveys/invalid-url/123` I don't really understand what's happening.

To make things worse I can't the site running locally due to all the legacy dependencies it uses not being compatible with my current dev machine.

From what I understand of CakePHP creating the new method and new .ctp file should be all I need to do in order to allow the page to work but there's obviously something I have missed.

Hoping some fellow S/O users can point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong.

**update**
The default routes are being added as they still have this in place:

`require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';`

They are using the [ACL from the docs][1] with AclExtras being installed but when I run  `./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_update`  they receive an error.

```
Error: Class QuestionsControllerDec2017 does not exist
```

There are a lot of files and folders that I can see that have dates in the names which I assume are older backups.  Is this now causing a problem with the reflection picking them up?

I'd edited Controller/UsersControllers.php to add in a an entry for the new method

```
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Surveys/report');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Surveys/download_report');
    // New Line below
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Surveys/pdf');
```

So is it a case that the aros_acos table is not out of date and needs an entry for this to be added but because of the previously error I can't add in dynamically.

** Update 2 **
The issue was I had missed out the permission creation so because of the legacy code access had to be created by using

`./Console/cake acl create aco Surveys pdf`

Comment: What sort of authentication and authorization is in place?

Comment: There's so many things that could cause this, it might not even be PHP doing it, but a server level redirect, impossible to tell from here, you'd have to further debug this. That being said, the route that you're showing will not connect to anything other then the `index()` method in the `SurveysController` class, if you want to connect to the `pdf()` method, then you need an additional route.

Comment: @ndm - that's what I also thought but they have other methods that are being called even though there's no wildcard in the rotues.php file such as surveys/report/123 calling the report method. From the backtrace I recorded that method it being called directly and not via the index method. I've checked .htaccess and that's not causing the redirect. It does called CakePlugin::routes() and ``` require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';``` after the routing entry I listed but that's it so I'm not sure how the routing it otherwise being set.

Comment: If the core's routes file is being included, then this is where catch-all routes will be introduced: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.24/lib/Cake/Config/routes.php#L17**.

Comment: @ndm So the rule Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('defaultRoute' => true)); should be being hit which would explain the lack of the 404. Perhaps it is the permission side. They are using a basic ACL like https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html and I added $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Surveys/pdf'); underneath the two existing lines of $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Surveys/report'); and $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Surveys/download_report'); but how do you refresh that in the DB?

Comment: @GregSchmidt they are using a basic authentication and acl as per the docs. When I run ./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_update though (they have AclExtras installed) it hits an error about a controller that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that whilst I have updated the UserController.php file I had not applied the ACL changes [as per the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html).

I could not use AclExtras due to an error caused by legacy backed up controllers breaking it otherwise this would have been the command that was required:

`./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_update`

So instead I used the manual way:

`./Console/cake acl create aco Surveys pdf`

Where Surveys is the controller name and pdf is the method name

Comment: Following on from this I also had to grant access to other roles otherwise they would not have access using ```./Console/cake acl grant Role.3 controllers/Surveys/pdf```